# search results using angular 5 forEach?

Tags: angular, typescript, foreach, angular5

i have a question , can we make a search and filter results using forEach ? 
i have a 4 dropdown list and one submit button and for example when i choose one or two criteria and click on submit the results will be displayed in a dataTable

like when i choose ABC value , the results will show all the data that contains that ABC word

is it possible ?

```html
<div class="nd_panel form_filter_home fixed" id="panel-filter-search-container">
  <h6 class="accordion-toggle" href="#filters" (click)="toggleCollapse($event)">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter text-primary"></span>
    <label>{{ 'search-filtre' | translate }}</label>
  </h6>
  <div class="nd_panel_content collapse" [ngClass]="{'in': !collapsed}" id="filters">
    <div class="container-fluid" id="panel-filter-search">
      <form [formGroup]="searchForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(searchForm.value)">
        <span class="text-danger" id="message-valid-filter-search">{{errorMessage}}</span>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-2" id="code-filter-search">
            <p-dropdown [options]="displayedEntityCodes" (onChange)="onCodeChange($event.value)" filter="filter"  placeholder="Code"
              [style]="{'width':'100%'}" [formControl]="searchForm.controls['selectedEntityCode']" >
            </p-dropdown>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-2" id="type-filter-search">
            <p-dropdown [options]="displayedEntityTypes" filter="filter" (onChange)="onTypeChange($event.value)" placeholder="Type"
              [style]="{'width':'100%'}" [formControl]="searchForm.controls['selectedEntityType']">

            </p-dropdown>
          </div>
         
          <div class="col-xs-2" id="profil-filter-search">
            <p-dropdown [options]="displayedEntityProfiles" filter="filter" (onChange)="onProfileChange($event.value)"  placeholder="Profil"
              [style]="{'width':'100%'}" [formControl]="searchForm.controls['selectedEntityProfile']">
            </p-dropdown>
          </div>
     <br>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="submit-button-filter-search"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>search </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
</div>
```

```js
  onSubmit(searchFormValue): void {
    if (this.isValid(searchFormValue)) {
      if (searchFormValue === searchFormValue.SelectedEntity) {
      }
      // do something to display filter results 
    }
```

and those are the values displayed on the dropdown lists :

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    this._userService.getEntities().subscribe(
      entities => {
        this.entities = entities;
        entities.forEach(entity => {
          if (this.entityTypes.filter(tp => tp.value === entity.type).length === 0) {
            this.entityTypes.push({ value: entity.type, label: entity.type });
            this.displayedEntityTypes.push({ value: entity.type, label: entity.type });
          }
          if (this.entityProfiles.filter(tp => tp.value === entity.profil).length === 0) {
            this.entityProfiles.push({ value: entity.profil, label: entity.profil });
            this.displayedEntityProfiles.push({ value: entity.profil, label: entity.profil });
          }

          this.entityCodes.push({ value: entity.code, label: entity.code });
          this.displayedEntityCodes.push({ value: entity.code, label: entity.code });
        });
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: How do you get your data, and where do you wish to display it?
Let's consider you retrieve all your data and display it inside a *ngFor, maybe you should consider creating a custom Pipe on that parent element where you dislay the result data?

Comment: well i'm getting the data from a database , and i want to display the filtered data in a table after clicking on the submit button, the problem is not where to display it but how to display the filtered results, for example i select "Jeizi" name as a value for the search and when i click on the submit button , it will lists all the users that have "Jeizi" as a name :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save the submitted filter value into a component public variable :

```
onSubmit(searchFormValue): void {
    if (this.isValid(searchFormValue)) {
      if (searchFormValue === searchFormValue.SelectedEntity) {
        this.submittedFilter = searchFormValue;
      } 
    }
}
```

Then, you could display the entities inside a *ngFor element

```
<div *ngFor="let myEntity of entities | myCustomFilter: submittedFilter"><div>
```

The 'myCustomFilter' can be defined using @Pipe annotation:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'myCustomFilter'})
export class MyCustomFilter implements PipeTransform {
  transform(entity: string, filter: string): number {
    // The behavior you are looking for
    // 'entity' can be a custom object
    return entity.includes(filter);
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to filter your data manually in code, and not in html, you can import your custom pipe and run it inside a method:

```
import { MyCustomFilter } from 'path/to/your/pipe';
constructor(private myCustomPipe: MyCustomFilter ) {}

// Return your filtered entities from the pipe
filterEntities() {
  return myCustomPipe.transform(this.entities, this.submittedFilter);
}
```

Then, bind the method to the input value like:

```
<p-table [value]="filterEntities()">
<p-table>
```

Hope it will help :)

Comment: thank you @Kapcash , i'm having trouble with the pipe now xD the behavior that i m looking for and how to put the pipe in a primeng dataTable cuz like this it won't work

Comment: Oh, well, that's another problem. The PrimeNg Table looks to use a private data render way, you don't use *ngFor yourself right?
If you just put the data you want to display, you should filter them before, in code. I'll edit my response to show you how.

Comment: yes ! this is what i was looking for ! THANK YOU :)